# How to prevent autofill of forms on same host in chromium browser?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, chromium, autofill

I have multiple application on localhost and now I'm writing new application and chromium is auto filling login form with data from different application (I probably click ok, to save password on my other app). The url is different because I still have my old app.

How can I make my form unique and tell chromium that my new app is different one?

Changing name attribute of the form don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only option is to delete the password for localhost, there is popup that allow to delete password when you click key icon on the right of the address bar.